# Uploading an Image using React and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

I've been having some issues uploading an image using React and Express and wanted to know if I was doing something wrong. Currently, I am using javascript FileReader to set my image state so I can show a realtime preview of the image to be uploaded before the form is submitted. My code for this looks like this:

```js
uploadImage = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        if (reader.readyState === 2) {
            this.setState({ picture: reader.result });
        }
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
}
```

Then, when the user submits the form I am creating a new FormData object and appending the file to it and sending it to my backend like this:

```js
createPost() {
    // Create form
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.state.picture);
    axios.post('/api/createPost', data).then((res) => console.log(res));
}
```

My express backend is using multer to handle the file upload but something doesn't seem to be working properly. I setup multer using diskStorage and then instantiate a new multer object with this storage using this code:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, __dirname + `/i/posts/${uuid().split('-').join('')}/`)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Then, within my createPost route I am doing what I found from a tutorial online (which worked no problem for them):

```js
app.post('/api/createPost', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    // Upload image
    console.log(req.file);
})
```

However, I have no luck uploading my image and the `console.log(req.file)` returns undefined. I'm really not sure what the issue could be as I've tried everything at this point so reaching out to all the people here at stackoverflow with the hopes someone has worked with this issue before for some help.

Thanks!

#### Edit:

Using [Nenad's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022517/uploading-an-image-using-react-and-express/67024836#67024836) suggestion I went back to setting a separate state to the file using `this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });`. However, this didn't fix my issue so I switched from using multer to using [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload). Then on my backend I was able to easily work with this data and upload the file appropriately:

```js
if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
}

const file = req.files.file;
const uploadDir = __dirname + `/i/posts/${uuid().split('-').join('')}/`

// Create new dir
fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir);

// Store upload directory
const uploadPath = uploadDir + Date.now() + '.' + file.name.split('.').pop();

// Store image path for database
const uploadPathArray = uploadPath.split('/')
const imageURL = `/${uploadPathArray.slice(Math.max(uploadPathArray.length - 2)).join('/')}`;

// Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
file.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

    // Then push everything into my database
});
```

If anyone is having the same issues with multer as I was this solution should work great!

Answer (score 0):

your backend code seems ok. But try from the frontend to to send `e.target.files[0]`. You can store that in some variable and then use it to append the `formData` in `createPost()`.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('file', e.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I had previously tried storing the file in a state using `this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });` and then appending that to the formData later with `data.append('file', this.state.file);` but when I checked the request sent to the backend it was always just and empty object.

Comment: Just took a peak at the entire request in the backend. It seems like the file is being sent in the request.files.file, however I've never seen this with multer as every documentation example I've seen is just request.file.